# How to callback function(json) Javascript with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have function like this :

```
<script>
    function sticky(json){something here}
</script>
```

Now I want to call this function with `Jquery` to show it inside one div element has an `ID = stickid` like this :

```
<script>
$("#stickid").each(function(){
             **How can I call that function?**
});
</script>

<div id="stickid">
</div>
```

How can I do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"so that it appears here"`? Do you simply want to execute that function? If so, just call it like this:  `sticky()`

Comment: Yes. Only execute function sticky(json).

Comment: Why can't you just call it?

Comment: But It does not run. I don't know why. Wait my example.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your JS console?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the exact answer to your question, but when I see this :

```
$("#stickid").each
```

I think this is porbably an issue. IDs are supposed to be unique in Html. So 'each' should not be needed. If you need to apply this to more than one element, use class instead:

```
<div class="stickId"></div>
<div class="stickId"></div>
    <script>
    $(".stickid").each(function(){
         sticky(your_json_data);
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your example the div `#stickid` won't exist when you run your javascript so nothing will happen.

It needs to be wrapped in a $(document).ready to ensure the DOM is loaded:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#stickid").each(function(){
        sticky();
    });
});
</script>

<div id="stickid">
</div>
```

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do though!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the solution :P `$(document).ready` FTW!